# Unit test mocking - doesnt make sense for me

Tags: php, unit-testing, junit, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to learn unit testing and have the following situation I just cant get my head around:

1. I have a model: SalesOrder - which models orders in an ecommerce store
2. The SalesOrder has a property called gift_message_id
3. The gift message id is an integer value and is a foreign key to a GiftMessage model
4. The GiftMessage model has a method that can take an order model and load a GiftMessage instance correctly based on the SalesOrder.

I am trying to write a test that accurately tests this behaviour but I am ending up with 2 mocks: 1 for the SalesOrder and 1 for the GiftMessage and it doesnt make sense.  What am i doing wrong here?

The method I am trying to test looks like this:

```
public function loadGiftMessageByOrderModel(SalesOrder $order)
{
    $giftMessageId = $order->getGiftMessageId();

    //if the order has a gift message id then load the gift message model and return it
    if ($giftMessageId !== false) {
        return new GiftMessage($giftMessageId);
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can this be unit tested, bearing in mind that the order and the gift message data are stored in a database.

Comment: I agree, unit testing is a joke

Comment: I think its valuable - but i just cant work out how to do this and make the test worthwhile

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand your description and what exactly you want to test. In general, if you want to test class X, you either mock or instantiate all external entities, regardless of how many those are. Of course, keeping things coupled loosely is an advantage here.

Comment: I want to test that, if an order has a gift message id, then a gift message model is returned otherwise false is returned.  I can easily mock the SalesOrder model to return a gift message id.  The bit i cant work out how to do is to load a new GiftMessage from that id and return it.  This is because the GiftMessage constructor takes an id and loads that from the database

Comment: How are you passing the db connection to the `GiftMessage` object? You have some global state here which makes your system hard to be tested and potentially really buggy.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using a db for testing which is why im trying to use mocks to simply test the correct return values

Comment: @MartyWallace yes, but I don't see any DB connection object passed around.

Comment: I am not following sorry.  This is maybe why i am struggling :( - how would you test the code in the example?

Comment: @MartyWallace please check the talk at http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=-FRm3VPhseI#t=1131s - you are having some sort of global state that does load your `GiftMessage` object at runtime implicitly (typically a call to a global function). This is an architectural mistake.

Comment: You are correct in that there is a global db connection.  But i want to be able to run the test with mocks.  i.e. there may be no orders and no gift messages in the system yet but i want to know that when there is the code will behave as expected.

Comment: @MartyWallace this case is not mockable until you either fake out the instantiated class (so you must ensure it was NOT autoloaded before - really really tricky!) or mock the db connection itself. You've dug yourself the tomb here :)

Comment: Ok thats why i am struggling then.  This fits into a larger framework which handles the db connection etc

Comment: @MartyWallace you don't need a bigger framework. Just explicitly inject your DB object by passing it down to your `GiftMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a method that calls a constructor and non-trivial work is done in the constructor, you are in trouble. The best option I would see from the above is to have the above class hold a `GiftMessageFactory` instance. Then you can mock the factory to validate that it is called with the appropriate values and the appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

As you've written the `loadGiftMessageByOrderModel` function and explained the GiftMessage constructor, I don't think you can easily unit test this code.  In order to cleanly test it, you need to load the GiftMessage from the DB in a method that is **not** the constructor.  Your constructor shouldn't be calling methods that interact with the database.  Another class or method should do that load, and then call the constructor.  Roughly, something like this:

```
public function loadGiftMessageByOrderModel(SalesOrder $order)
{
    $giftMessageId = $order->getGiftMessageId();

    //if the order has a gift message id then load the gift message model and return it
    if ($giftMessageId !== false) {
        // $giftMessageLoader handles loading from the DB; it doesn't create a GiftMessage object
        $giftMessageRecord = $giftMessageLoader.loadById( $giftMessageId );
        // $giftMessageFactory actually calls the constructor to create a GiftMessage
        return $giftMessageFactory.createFromRecord( $giftMessageRecord );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, you can mock the `$giftMessageLoader.loadById` call so you control what's returned from the database.  You'll also be able to test that the `$giftMessageFactory` calls the `GiftMessage` constructor appropriately and creates the proper object.

The overall lesson here is that constructors should be simple.  They can validate parameters so the object is constructed correctly, but they probably shouldn't be calling other significant pieces of your application.